# ASP.NET Web API AllowAnonymous should not create new session

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

We have asp.net API (**NOT** core).

For every request (including **anonymous** endpoints) we creates a new session which sends it to redis.
So, we should not need to have a session for **anonymous** requests.

We have the following code in `global.asax.cs`

```
protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Required);
    }
```

Can I check in the `Application_PostAuthorizeRequest` method - does the action have the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute?

If I move the code from `Application_PostAuthorizeRequest` to, say, `ActionFilterAttribute`, then when I call `HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior` I get an error:

```
HttpContext.SetSessionStateBehavior' can only be invoked before 'HttpApplication.AcquireRequestState' event is raised.
```

Comment: just check `var routeData = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
    if (routeData.DataTokens.ContainsKey("HasAllowAnonymous"))` in method `Application_PostAuthorizeRequest`

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens.ContainsKey("HasAllowAnonymous") - always false for me

Comment: It's been a while using asp.net api, but I think the main issue is situated in the request pipeline. Try changing Application_PostAuthorizeRequest to Application_BeginRequest . This should make sure that your session state behavoir is set before the actual event that tries to acquire it is raised.

Comment: To elaborate on the above, put your check on the AllowAnonymous in the Application_BeginRequest and decide based on the fact if it leads to an AllowAnonymous  ActionMethod or not to either SetSessionStateBehavior or not.